# e.row.rowType value return NULL

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, datarow

```
protected void passSubContractorInfoToNewPage(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Sub_Contractor subC = (Sub_Contractor)e.Row.DataItem;
            HyperLink LoadSubContractorDetails = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("LoadSubContractorDetails");
            LoadSubContractorDetails.NavigateUrl = ResolveUrl(@"~/SubContractDetails.aspx?id=" + subC.id.ToString());
        }
}
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" OnRowDataBound="passSubContractorInfoToNewPage" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" CssClass="gridview" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataSourceID="GridDataSource1"> 
        <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="InvoiceInfoID" /> 
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Company Name" HeaderText="Company Name" SortExpression="Name" />   
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="LoadSubContractorDetails" runat="server" Text="Show Details"/>
             </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>



   </asp:GridView>
     <asp:SqlDataSource ID="GridDataSource1" runat="server"   
          ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings:ClarkesTest4FromMaster1ConnectionString %>"  
         SelectCommand="SELECT id, [Company Name] FROM [Sub Contractor] ORDER BY [Company Name]" >
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This returns an error with subContractor as NULL 
with error as:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'Sub_Contractor'.
```

Also tried

```
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DataRowView view = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
```

but still no joy.....

why isnt it picking up sub contractor can someone tell me?

Thanks

Comment: So _what_ is the datasource of the `GridView`, what does the debugger tell you about `e.Row.DataItem`? You haven't shown us `GridDataSource1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type
>   'Sub_Contractor'.

This is self-explanatory. So the underlying datasource of every `GridViewRow` is a `DataRowView`.

But i don't understand this:

> Also tried

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    DataRowView view = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
```

> but still no joy.....

That should work without a problem. So i assume that this causes a different error which you haven't mentioned yet.